# Hex to binary convert in assembly

Tags: assembly

I wrote this program to take input of A-E by user and enlarge it using bit pattern and enlarge it for example:

```
$ $ $$
$*****$
$*****$
$ $ $$ 
$*****$
$*****$
$ $ $$
```

Here is my code:

```
Bits 16
org 0x100
jump Start

s1: db 'Enter a Upper case Letter (A-E)  $'
s2: db 'ERROR. Invalid Letter. Enter Capital(A-E). $'

;Bit PATTERN DECLARATION FOR EACH LETTER in HEX
      ;1  2  3  4  5  6  7
A: db 1F,11,11,1f,11,11,11
B: db 1E,11,11,1E,11,11,1E
C: db 1F,10,10,10,10,10,1F
D: db 1E,11,11,11,11,11,1E
E: db 1F,10,10,1f,10,10,1F


screen: mov ah,09             ; Clears screen and change cursor color 
    mov cx, 1000          ; space 1000times 
    mov bl, 9e            ; Change of color
    int 10
    ret

cursor: mov ah,02         ;Positon cursor
    mov bh,00         ; page 0
    mov dh,10         ; row 10
    mov dx,0          ; column 0
    int 10
    ret

Prom: mov ah,09         ;Prompt user to input
  mov dx, s1
  int 21
  ret

read: mov ah,01         ;read charachter and Echo
  int 21
  int 21
  ret

error1: mov ah,09       ; error display message
    mov dx, s2
    int 21   
    jmp start

 compA:
    cmp al, 40h
    jl error1
 compE:  cmp al ,45h
    jg error1
    call Print

print:         

start:
Call screen
call cursor
call prom
call read
call compA

;end
```

I thought of declaring each Letter with hex, convert hex to binary and let a reader step through the binary and display on screen.

Any suggestions on how to build the converter (hex to binary) and reader to display `$` for `1` and  `" "` for `0`?

Comment: The letter patterns are not declared as hexadecimal strings, so there is no need to do conversion from hexadecimal. As you are not going to display the values as binary numbers there is no need to do conversion to a binary representation. Just work with the bits in the byte values that you have.

Comment: would you say i declare an array pattern  for each letter and just let a reader step through that and display?